# Typing Status Smack 4.1

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

Hey I am trying to get typing status when the other person starts writing even though it is returning an empty message with the state as a message but it is coming from proccessMessage method. Shouldn't it be returned in the stateChanged? I haven't enabled any PacketProvider though, Do i have to do it so this would be returned in the stateChanged method? I would appreciate any help.

```
   newChat = chatmanager.createChat(contactUsername + sc.DOMAIN, new ChatStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(Chat chat, ChatState state) {
            if (ChatState.composing.equals(state)) {
               Log.d("Chat State",chat.getParticipant() + " is typing..");
            } else if (ChatState.gone.equals(state)) {
               Log.d("Chat State",chat.getParticipant() + " has left the conversation.");
            } else {
             Log.d("Chat State",chat.getParticipant() + ": " + state.name());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
            System.out.println("Received message: " + message);
        }
   });
```

Logs:

```
06-15 14:28:47.679    9949-9983/com.example.example I/System.out﹕ Received message: <message to='+931111111111@example.com' from='+930000000000@example.com/Spark 2.6.3' id='AUJG0-42' type='chat'><thread>097uC9</thread><inactive xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates'/></message>
```

Comment: regarding my answer below, have you implemented the sending side yourself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a general answer, there might be better ones, but this works for sure, it might contain stuff you already know, but I guess it can't hurt.

Base assumption - `composing` messages are messages where the body is null, and the xml of the whole message contains a `ChatState` tag with one of `active, composing, paused, inactive, gone` values, and what you're looking for is `composing`, and it's counterpart, `paused`.

That being said, on the **receiving** component you need something like this (modify it to your needs):

```
yourComponent.addMessageListener(new PacketListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void processPacket(Packet packet) throws NotConnectedException
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Message msg = (Message) packet;
                        String msg_xml = msg.toXML().toString();

                        if (null != msg.getBody())
                        {
                          //handle as a regular chat message....
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (msg_xml.contains(ChatState.composing.toString()))
                            {
                              //handle is-typing, probably some indication on screen
                            }
                            else if (msg_xml.contains(ChatState.paused.toString()))
                            {
                             // handle "stopped typing" 
                            }
                       }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                    }
               }
            });
```

EDIT:

Your log message shows you got an `inactive` message, so for starters, try filtering **all** the messages, and find the pattern of what your looking for, to see if the sending side is even sending what you need.

A good way to understand would be to use another client that you know for a fact that's sending the composing state, and see what you get in your filter (e.g. under linux you could use pidgin or empathy for the sending side).

EDIT 2:

As per requested, I'm also adding some of the **sending-side** components for a more complete picture, again, this is a general example for reference purpose, and could be optimized and changed.

First, implement a custom EditText that implements a TextWatcher with a small thread that fires with the delay you want from the last text change to say "I stopped typing", set your interval as you want:

```
public class MyIsTypingEditText extends EditText implements TextWatcher
{
  private static final int TypingInterval = 800;

  //your listener interface that you implement anonymously from the Activity
  public interface OnTypingModified
  {
      public void onIsTypingModified(EditText view, boolean isTyping);
  }

  private OnTypingModified typingChangedListener;

  //members you would need for the small thread that declares that you have stopped typing
  private boolean currentTypingState = false;
  private Handler handler = new Handler();
  private Runnable stoppedTypingNotifier = new Runnable()
  {
      @Override
      public void run() 
      {
          //part A of the magic...
          if(null != typingChangedListener)
          {
            typingChangedListener.onIsTypingModified(MyIsTypingEditText.this, false);
            currentTypingState = false;
          }
      }
   };

  public MyIsTypingEditText(Context context)
  {
      super(context);
      this.addTextChangedListener(this);
  }

  public void setOnTypingModified(OnTypingModified typingChangedListener)
  {
      this.typingChangedListener = typingChangedListener;
  }

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
  {
      //part B of the magic...
      if(null != typingChangedListener)
      {
          if(!currentTypingState)
          {
              typingChangedListener.onIsTypingModified(this, true);
              currentTypingState = true;
          }

          handler.removeCallbacks(stoppedTypingNotifier);
          handler.postDelayed(stoppedTypingNotifier, TypingInterval);
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,   int after) { }


  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start,   int before, int after) { }

  }
```

Next, in the activity that handles your chat, add a new anonymous interface and implement it's callback with your state-changing-message sending method call, this part C of the magic, as this will send your state corresponding to the TextWatcher mini-thread:

```
    yourIsTypingEditText.setOnTypingModified(new MyIsTypingEditText.OnTypingModified()
    {
        @Override
        public void onIsTypingModified(EditText view, boolean isTyping)
        {
            XmppConnectionClass.Composing composing = (isTyping) ? XmppConnectionClass.Composing.isTyping : XmppConnectionClass.Composing.stoppedTyping;

            XmppConnectionClass.getInstance().sendIsComposing(composing);
        }
    });
```

And last but not least, in your connection handler class you should have the following:

```
//.... other stuff

//a mini enum Composing class for state setting
public enum Composing
{
  private ChatState state;

  Composing(ChatState state)
  {
      this.state = state;
  }

  isTyping(ChatState.composing), stoppedTyping(ChatState.paused);

    public ChatState getState()
    {
        return (state);
    }
}

 //.... other stuff

 public boolean sendIsComposing(Composing composing)
{
    try
    {
        Message msg = new Message(...);

        //other stuff...

        msg.setBody(null);
        msg.addExtension(new ChatStateExtension(composing.getState()));

        //other stuff...

        this.sendMessage(msg);
        return (true);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return (false);
    }
}
```

Hope this Helps.

Comment: i know i can parse the xml, but my question is why is it returning in processMessage and not in stateChanged? the problem is when i receive it. will it always come in proccessMessage?

Comment: From your question here I understand it worked for you? The reason is that ChatState is actualy an extension, and it is passed through an empty bodied message, [here is a reference](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/chatstates/ChatStateManager.html) it's down at the bottom in setChatState.

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting, it's from a cell phone :)

Comment: thanks for the clarification TommySM, could you help me in my second question please TommySM? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879799/android-smack-messageeventmanager-not-compiling

Comment: @TommySM do i need to send this packet from somewhere? like do need to write override onFocusChanged method of ChatActivity's edittext?

Comment: @Newbiee yes, you send this packet when you type, what I did is implement my own TypingEditText (extends EditText implements TextWatcher) that overrides afterTextChanged and listens to the typing, when you start it sends a composing state, when you stop - you send the paused state (on the receiving end makes the "is typing" message disappear)

Comment: my sendMessage method is in the xmpp connection class itself, and everything else like state change listener is also there.so how will i be able to call setCurrentState in my Chat Activity?

Comment: @TommySM   so my main question is how to call setCurrentState from ChatActivity class? as my Chat object is local for sendMessage method and listener is also defined in SmackConnection class only

Comment: @Newbiee what you're doing is correct, all you are missing is an interface that you define and create inside your TypingEditText, then in your ChatActivity you add a new anonymous instance of that interface that implements it, in that callback you call the sendMessage (you should add a sendComposingState method)

Comment: @Newbiee I'll edit my answer here and add a general example for the sending side components

Comment: @TommySM i have added my chatActivity code if you want to have a look at it,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108933/discussion-between-newbiee-and-tommysm).

Comment: @TommySM do you have any idea about sending notification using GCM when user is offline in xmpp?

Comment: @Newbiee  I used a third-party solution for a while, implementing GCM on my own is currently on the ToDo list, will start shortly

Comment: okay, which third-party solution did you used? if you can say that

Comment: Parse, but it's obsolete now, bought by Facebook and been declared End Of Life

Comment: Okay @TommySM thanks for the help, right now i am using trigger on ofoffline table which can then transfer the data into another table and on that table i will periodically run the code to send the push. is it the good approach? just for the clarification though !!

Comment: depends on what periodically means, try to keep it as near-real time as possible

Comment: Thanks a lot. Only thing i can add is , you need to add attributes to custom view's constructor and pass it to the super class.

Answer (score 1):

I have better implementation idea for watching chat state of user.

```
             if (packet instanceof Message) {
                Message message = (Message) packet;
                if (message.getBody() != null) {
                    processMessage(message);
                } else {
                    //process chat states here
                    processChatState(message);
                }
            }
```

The method for `processChatState` is

```
 private void processChatState(Message message) {
        ExtensionElement element = message.getExtension(ChatStateExtension.NAMESPACE);

        if (element != null) {
            switch (element.getElementName()) {
                case "composing":
                    updateStatusOfUser("typing...");
                    break;
                case "paused":
                    updateStatusOfUser("online");
                    break;
                case "active":
                    updateStatusOfUser("online");
                    break;
                case "inactive":
                    updateStatusOfUser("online");
                    break;
                case "gone":
                    updateStatusOfUser("online");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```